# Depth first search: Trying to count the amount of nodes with a specific characteristic (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search

I have a tree where some nodes have a certain characteristic. I wish to count the amount of nodes in the tree which have this characteristic by using a DFS-like algorithm. However, I am using return values incorrectly. If a node with this characteristic is found, I want some sort of counter to increment, otherwise the counter does not increment.

This is quite simple, but I haven't been able to implement it properly.

```
    private int dfs(Node node) {

    for(Node n: node.children){ 
        if(n != null && n.someOtherCondition){
            return 1 + dfs(n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: My bad. Forgot to change the name of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return immediately when you find a matching node: count them, and return at the end.

```
private int dfs(Node node) {
  int count = 0;
  for(Node n: node.children){ 
    if(n != null && n.someOtherCondition){
      count += 1;       // Count this node.
      count += dfs(n);  // Count this node's children.

      // Alternatively: count += 1 + dfs(n); split up for clarity.
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Note that you're not actually checking the condition on the parameter `node`, so you won't actually count the node you start from, if that matches the condition; depending on your application, this may or may not be necessary. If you actually want to count this node too:

```
private int dfs(Node node) {
  if (node == null) return 0;

  int count = node.someOtherCondition ? 1 : 0;

  for(Node n: node.children){ 
    count += dfs(n);
  }

  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should accumulate the results of recursively calling DFS on **all** children instead of returning on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int dfs(Node node) {
  int count = 0;

  for(Node n: node.children){ 
    if(n != null && n.someOtherCondition){
        // check if the child-node has children
        if(n.children.length > 0){
          count = count + dfs(n); // recursively count the grandchildren aswell
        }
        count = count + 1; // add one because we meet the condition once on this level
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: The `if(n.children.length > 0){` check is redundant: the recursive call simply doesn't have anything to iterate, and will return immediately anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

```
private int dfs(Node node) {
    int count = node.someOtherCondition ? 1 : 0;
    for (Node child : node.children)
        if (child != null)
            count += dfs(node);
    return count;
}
```